# XML get people where date starts with 2013

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Can someone please help me with this problem.
I have a web application and need to do the following:
How can I get the age of all the persons with gender 'male' and date STARTS WITH 2013

Thank you so much for your help

I have this XML:

```
<company>
  <department>
    <departmentname>Dep 1</departmentname>
    <people>
      <person>
        <name>Sean</name>
        <date>2011-10-10</date>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <age>40</age>
      </person>
      <person>
        <name>John</name>
        <date>2013-10-18</date>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <age>45</age>
      </person>
      <person>
        <name>Linda</name>
        <date>2012-09-10</date>
        <gender>female</gender>
        <age>42</age>
      </person>
      <person>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <date>2013-10-01</date>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <age>35</age>
      </person>
    </people>
  </department>
  <department>
    <departmentname>Dep 2</departmentname>
    <people>
      <person>
        <name>Art</name>
        <date>2012-09-10</date>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <age>38</age>
      </person>
      <person>
        <name>Christina</name>
        <date>2013-10-20</date>
        <gender>female</gender>
        <age>45</age>
      </person>
      <person>
        <name>Marie</name>
        <date>2011-09-10</date>
        <gender>female</gender>
        <age>49</age>
      </person>
    </people>
  </department>
</company>
```

Here is my c# code:

```
string year = "2013";

protected List<string> GetPersons(string year)
{
    XElement company= XElement.Load(Server.MapPath(XMLfil));

    var persons= (from a in company.Elements("department").Elements("people").Elements("person")
                  where (string)a.Element("gender").Value == 'male' && (string)a.Element("date").Value == STARTS WITH 2013
                  select (string)(a.Element("age"))).ToList<string>();
    return persons; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Value.StartsWith("2013")?

Comment: Do you need to return the age values or the person elements?

Comment: I need to return the ages of all the men with year 2013.

Comment: Thank you gt, Value.StartsWith("2013") works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string year = "2013";

protected List<string> GetPersons(string year)
{
    XElement company= XElement.Load(Server.MapPath(XMLfil));

    var persons= (from a in company.Elements("department").Elements("people").Elements("person")
                  where (string)a.Element("gender").Value == 'male' && (string)a.Element("datum").Value.StartsWith(year)
                  select (string)(a.Element("age"))).ToList<string>();
    return persons;
}
```

Or try DateTime.Parse on that and compare only the year. That would be better when for example the format of dates in your xml changed.

Comment: Thank you. I hope (string)a.Element("datum").Value.StartsWith(year)
works. I will try it tonight when I'm at my computer at home. I'll let you know.

Comment: How would the code look like if I use DateTime.Parse? I'm sorry but I'm new to this and have never used DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

```
from p in company.Descendants("person")
let date = (string)p.Element("date")
where (string)p.Element("gender") == "male" &&
      date != null && date.StartsWith(year) // pass year as a string
select (string)p.Element("age")
```

Output:

```
45
35
```

But I suggest you to create method which accepts integer value (thus year number is an integer) and returns list of integer values (because age is integer). Also use self-descriptive name for method, which shows your intent:

```
protected List<int> GetMaleAges(int year)
{
    var company= XElement.Load(Server.MapPath(XMLfil));
    var ages = from p in company.Descendants("person")
               let date = (DateTime?)p.Element("date") // use DateTime
               where (string)p.Element("gender") == "male" &&
                     date.HasValue && date.Value.Year == year
               select (int)p.Element("age")

    return ages.ToList();
}
```

---

NOTE: you can also tread date as `DateTime` values instead of string

```
from p in company.Descendants("person")
let date = (DateTime?)p.Element("date")
where (string)p.Element("gender") == "male" &&
       date.HasValue && date.Value.Year == year // pass year as integer
select (int)p.Element("age")
```

---

Also you can use XPath (most laconic solution)

```
string xpath = String.Format(
   "//person[gender='male' and date[starts-with(., '{0}')]]/age", year);
return company.XPathSelectElements(xpath).Select(a => (int)a);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not familiar to XPath so I prefer to use xElement. The output should be 45, 35, 45 since we don´t need to take into account the department name.
I hope the line date.StartsWith(year)  works. I will try it tonight when I'm at my computer at home.

Comment: @user2939293 nope, output should be `45, 35` because you are also filtering by gender

Comment: Thank you! date.StartsWith(year) works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with "Contains"(`String.Contains`) check so that in case if the date format changes then also your query will work.

```
var persons = (from a in company.Descendants("person")
                   where a.Element("gender").Value.ToLower() == "male" && a.Element("date").Value.Contains("2013")
                   select a.Element("age").Value).ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys!
I had never Heard of StartsWith. It now works thanks to you!

Here's my solution:

```
string year = "2013";

protected List<string> GetPersons(string year)
{
    XElement company= XElement.Load(Server.MapPath(XMLfil));

    var persons= (from a in company.Elements("department").Elements("people").Elements("person")
                  where (string)a.Element("gender").Value == 'male' && a.Element("date").Value.StartsWith(year)                      
                 select (string)(a.Element("age"))).ToList<string>();
    return persons; 
}
```